# How do I run cross validation on a decision tree in an uplift model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, model, caret

I have this model from the `uplift` package,

```
mod.RF <- upliftRF(as.numeric(response) ~.
                   +trt(group), 
                   data = df,
                   mtry = 3,
                   ntree = 100,
                   split_method = "KL",
                   minsplit = 200,
                   interaction.depth = 1, #also try with id = 2
                   verbose = TRUE)
```

I want to make predictions and evaluate those predictions. I'd like to create a test set with 10-fold cross validation. I know how to do that in `caret` when that it being used to make a model.

How do I evaluate the tree using 10-fold cross validation outside of `caret`?

Put another way - how can I make new data that I can fill in for the `newdata` object in `predict()`and can I use cross validation to do that?

Comment: Not asked, but a relevant addition given the question title: a good metric to use for cross-validating uplift models is the transformed outcome loss `T*Y/p(T) - (1-T)Y(1-p(T))`, where T is a binary indicator if the individual received treatment.

A nice explanation is given in     
Hitsch, G. J., & Misra, S. (2018). [Heterogeneous Treatment Effects and Optimal Targeting Policy Evaluation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3111957). SSRN.

Answer (score 0):

This model is not a decision tree, it is a random forest with `ntree = 100` trees.

Here is one general way to do cross validation with the `modelr` package.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("modelr")
library("uplift")

# Use example in upliftRF's documentation
set.seed(123)
dd <- sim_pte(n = 1000, p = 20, rho = 0, sigma =  sqrt(2), beta.den = 4)
dd$treat <- ifelse(dd$treat == 1, 1, 0)

### fit uplift random forest

uplift_model <- function(data) {
  # It is easier to write a separte "fit" function when
  # there are many parameters
  upliftRF(y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + trt(treat),
           data = data,
           mtry = 3,
           ntree = 100,
           split_method = "KL",
           minsplit = 200,
           verbose = TRUE)
}
predict_uplift <- function(mod, newdata) {
  # For some reason, necessary with `predict.upliftRF`
  newdata <- as_tibble(newdata)
  predict(mod, newdata)
}

# 5-fold cross validation
folds <- crossv_kfold(dd, 3)

folds %>%
  mutate(model = map(train, uplift_model)) %>%
  mutate(pred = map2(model, test, predict_uplift))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   train          test           .id   model          pred           
#>   <list>         <list>         <chr> <list>         <list>         
#> 1 <S3: resample> <S3: resample> 1     <S3: upliftRF> <dbl [334 x 2]>
#> 2 <S3: resample> <S3: resample> 2     <S3: upliftRF> <dbl [333 x 2]>
#> 3 <S3: resample> <S3: resample> 3     <S3: upliftRF> <dbl [333 x 2]>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>